# Groovy CliBuilder: any method defined?

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface

I'm very new to Groovy.
Very simple question about the code found in CliBuilder.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/index.html?overview-summary.html

```
def cli = new CliBuilder(name:'ls')
cli.a('display all files')
cli.l('use a long listing format')
cli.t('sort by modification time')
def options = cli.parse(args)
assert options // would be null (false) on failure
assert options.arguments() == ['*.groovy']
assert options.a && options.l && options.t
```

The CliBuilder class behaves as knowing whatever methods we want to call in advance.  By what Groovy's feature it can be supported?

Comment: the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Runtime metaprogramming](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.5.1/html/documentation/#_runtime_metaprogramming).

If you want to create your own class with "dynamic methods", the easiest way is to implement the `GroovyInterceptable` interface and add the `invokeMethod` method to your class.

```
class Interception implements GroovyInterceptable {

    def definedMethod() { }

    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        'invokedMethod'
    }
}
```

Whenever a method is called on an instance if the class `Interception`, `invokeMethod` is called *instead*. Note that this is also true for methods actually defined in the class (e.g. `definedMethod`)

You can use the metaClass to call the actual method like this

```
class Interception implements GroovyInterceptable {

    def definedMethod() { }

    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        if (name == "actualMethod") {
            return metaClass.invokeMethod(this, name, args)
        }
        return "invokedMethod: $name($args)"
    }

    def actualMethod() {
        return 'hello there'
    }
}
```

Here a call to `actualMethod` still goes through `invokeMethod`, however `invokeMethod` contains logic to call the actual method.

There are some other ways (see link on top) to acomplish similar behavior, but I found this to be the easiest.

Note that runtime metaprogramming is incompatible with `@CompileStatic` unless you add a [`TypeCheckingExtension`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.5.1/html/documentation/#Typecheckingextensions-Workingwithextensions) to mitigate this.

[Run Example](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5189243307556864)

Comment: Thank you! It gets clear.  Any method call on CliBuilder instance is intercepted, and dispatched to the method that can register the calee name as a short option, then the actual method call for the calee method is skipped.